# Want to pass data from componentDidMount but it's always undefined

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Getting data from server in componentdidmount and passing to handlesubmit function but it always returns undefined:

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(BASE_URL_API + "/payments/subscriptions/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
  }

  handleSubmit = async event => {

    event.preventDefault();

    const data = this.props;

    console.log("Token is: ", data);

  };
```

Comment: there is more than one problem here: You have to call `res.json().then....` instead of `res.json()).then...`, you try to set a `state` but you are reading the `props` ( `const data = this.props`)

Comment: Wait, you have data from props or it's a mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly it should be `const data = { this.state };` since you're storing the data in the state.

The `props` object is used for data that is passed into your component as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: the promise chain in the `componentDidMount` is also not correct...

Answer (score 0):

It should be `const { data } = this.props;` instead of `const data = this.props;`